# Is it possible to have a website, like a text-based document?

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

When you view the source code of a website - you get a text-based document:

```
view-source:http://example.com/
```

I suppose, what I am asking is: is possible to have: 'http://example.com/index.txt', and remove the: '/index.txt' (using .htaccess) - so the website acts like a text document.

Comment: It's just a matter of configuring the web server, it the default document is index.txt, it will be served.

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a `.htaccess` file in your root directory and set the directory index like so:

```
DirectoryIndex index.txt
```

[.htaccess Guide - DirectoryIndex Uses](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/)

In most cases, I would advise against this as you cannot use any form of code or formatting within your document. This means no hyperlinking, no images, nothing apart from plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The important aspect in this is the `Content-Type` HTTP header sent by the server. If it's the usual `text/html`, the browser will interpret the document as HTML. To serve plain text, the header needs to specify `text/plain`. You can configure Apache to [serve files as plain text using](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype):

```
AddType text/plain .html .txt
```

Add whatever file extensions you want to that list (here: `.html .txt`).

Comment: Thanks, it has styled the font from: 'Times New Roman' to: 'Courier New' - of which is what I wanted.

Comment: Note that such presentational details are entirely up to each individual browser. If you actually want to control fonts and such, use HTML and properly format, escape and style your content to appear as you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you're displaying plain text documents whose format is critical (frames, tables or columnar reports), you can wrap them in a `<PRE> </PRE>` couple of tags, or even better, `<HTML><BODY><PRE>` on top and `</PRE></BODY></HTML>` on bottom, which ensures wider compatibility.  You can do this "on the fly" or mantain copies on disk/db for future use.
The `<PRE>` tag is used to tell the browser that the text enclosed is **preformatted**, and is usually rendered with a monospace font like Courier or similars, preserving text formatting, column alignment, etc.

Comment: I misunderstood your initial requirement, nonetheless the usage of <PRE></PRE> might be a valid option in many cases.